# vue-resource and JSONP working example

Tags: jsonp, vue-resource

I'm struggling to make JSONP request using vue-resource. Can anybody provide some working examples demonstrating the proper way of defining jsonp callback, handling the call within Vue component and so on.

Thanks

**EDIT:**For other fellows, let’s clarify the situation a bit. What was the point - I have a non-authenticated user on the site and I wanted to let him do some action that requires authentication (create post e.g.). However, at the very end of creating post I wanted to show him sign-in modal window, let him log in using social oAuth providers and on successful login, let the post being approved and so on. Problem was that this call from the front-end toward different domains (social providers) was blocked (CORS issue) and than I tried to use JSONP to overcome the obstacle. Trying to setup JSONP call  had spent a really lot of my time and finally I decided to go with totally different approach:

At the end of the process of creating the post, a cookie is created, caring the info what was the action that was interrupted with all necessary details. After that, a login modal is shown. Whole login process is done from the server side, and at the end, when identity of an user is confirmed, redirect to initial page is made. Further on, cookie is checked and based on the data, interrupted action continues execution successfully since the user is authenticated now.

@bryceadams thanks again for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

How you handle it in your component will depend on your implementation, but typically it's done in a [method](https://vuejs.org/guide/events.html) - like if you had a form and then on submitting the form you called a method that made a JSONP request.

**Here's an example call**. Note that the important part is the `jsonp` option where you set the callback. This can vary based on where you're making the request to. Often it will be `callback`, but in my case I was working with MailChimp where it was `c`.

```
var options = {
    jsonp: 'c'
}

this.$http.jsonp('https://website.com', options).then(function(data){
    console.log(data.json());
}, function(error) {
    // handle errors
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn’t able to setup this JSONP correctly, or at least to use it successfully in my case. I will edit my question trying to explain what was the workaround.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to change the log message to console.log(data.json()) as response does not exist. Thanks for your help getting this going.